# How to get the same Python code formatting with PyCharm and Vim?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, vim, pycharm, code-editor

We have a 3 years old Django codebase in production.
All the code has been written by a single developer using PyCharm.
Now, a second developer is joining the team. He used to work with Vim.

We want to work together, being sure, that when running "reformat code" tool, both IDEs produce the exact same output in both development environments.

#### What we tried for now

- We exported `.code_editor` configuration file from the PyCharm of the first developer. However, most of the exported formatting options are proprietary to intelliJ IDE, starting with "ij_" prefix. Which means this configuration file can not be used totally in Vim.
- We took a look at formatting tools like Black and YAPF that come with "forced" coding style. However, since this coding style differs from the one in PyCharm, we would need to change the whole codebase, file per file. This seems cumbersome and not the best suited/safe solution, when dealing with production code.

Any idea? it seems very strange to me that there is no easy way to configure 2 IDEs to format the code the same way.

Thanks!

Comment: Does PyCharm have a command line driven method of reformatting code? The requirement could just be "passes pycharm code formatting" and let developers get there however they want.

Comment: PyCharm has a command line formatter: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-formatter.html

You can make a shell script and hook it into git to make sure the code is formatted on commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a shortcut to run [Darker](https://github.com/akaihola/darker/) to apply Black reformatting on just the modified lines instead of the whole file. The documentation shows how to use Darker with Vim, PyCharm and VS Code.